# How to tell if python's ZipFile.writestr() failed because file is full?

Tags: python, exception, zip

Without using zip64 extensions, a Zip file cannot be more than 2GB in size, so trying to write to a file that would put it over that limit won't work.  I expected that when such a writing was attempted, it would raise an exception, but I've not been able to cause one to be raised.  (The documentation is silent on the matter.)  If an exception doesn't get raised in such a circumstance, how would I (efficiently) go about determining if the write succeeded or not?

Comment: How about getting the content of the file and saving it to a string, then check the lenght of the string (one char is one byte) and choose whether or not to proceed? Edit: now that I think about it, that way might not be very efficient.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?  The Python 2.7.2 docs have a [zipfile.LargeZipFile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.LargeZipFile)  exception which is raised "when a ZIP file would require ZIP64 functionality but that has not been enabled."

Comment: If true, you should [report this as a bug](http://bugs.python.org/). Errors should not pass silently. (Edit: assuming you are using the latest version, that is.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an exception trying to write big strings to a zip archive:

```
$ python write-big-zip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "write-big-zip.py", line 7, in <module>
    myzip.writestr('arcname%d'% i, b'a'*2**30)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 1125, in writestr
    self._writecheck(zinfo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 1020, in _writecheck
    raise LargeZipFile("Zipfile size would require ZIP64 extensions")
zipfile.LargeZipFile: Zipfile size would require ZIP64 extensions
```

Using the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Write big strings to zip file until error."""
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('big.zip', 'w') as myzip:
    for i in range(4):
        myzip.writestr('arcname%d'% i, b'a'*2**30)
```

Comment: Not sure why I wasn't catching the exception before, but clearly one is being raised, as you'd expect.  Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

size = os.path.getsize("file") #Get the size of the file.
size = size/1073741824 #Converting bytes to GB.

if size < 2: # < is probably safer than <=
        #do the zipping
else:
        print "The file is too large!"
```

This isn't ideal, of course, but it might serve as a temporary solution until a better one has been found.
Again, I don't think this is a very good way of using zip. But if there is no appropriate exception (which there should), it might serve as a temporary solution.

Comment: Not sure if this could be used on the zip file, as it is still open.